# Query aggregation with List of Objects

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections

I have some objects that which are defined like following:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    public string CustName{ get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
}

public class DetailReport
{
    public Customer TheCustomer { get; set; }
    public IList<Orders> OrderList { get; set; }
}
```

For reporting purposes I am getting an object of type List from which I create a tabular report.

```
IList<DetailReport> detailReport
```

All is well until I get a requirement to generate a chart based on OrderDate and get total number of orders for that day.

So now I have to take out data which have a DateTime value (OrderDate) and Count of order Ids on that particular day.

Can I do something like the following?

```
from orderdata in detailReport.OrderList.........
```

I require the unique date and the Count of OrderIds on that day from detailReport list

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You don't have `OrderId` field anywhere.

Comment: Sorry Forgot to paste it there. Now it is ok

Comment: Why does your class definitions have a `()`? And what is `Orders`? I only see an `Order` class. Does your code really compile? Have you actually written this code in Visual Studio?

Comment: Well, that is fixed. It is something similar to this in the VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
 var result = report.SelectMany(x => x.OrderList)
                               .GroupBy(x => x.OrderDate.Date)
                               .Select(x => new
                                   {
                                       OrderDate = x.Key,
                                       OrderCount = x.Count()
                                   });
```

Please check [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OAdIO0) for sample data I have used.

Comment: What if the OrderDate is being saved upto the Seconds like for instance in the db I have dates like '2014-11-07 03:58:46.000' Can I just group upto the Date part?

Comment: Then simply group by `Date` proerty of `DateTime` object. Your Groupby should look like: `GroupBy(x => x.OrderDate.Date.Date)`

Answer (score 1):

You can write it this way:

```
var Result = (from reportdata in detailReport
              from orderdata  in reportdata.OrderList
                 group orderdata by orderdata.OrderDate.Date into g
                 select new
                       {
                         OrderDate = g.Key,
                         Count = g.Count()
                       }).ToList();
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mvcBlZ)

or utilize `SelectMany()` to flatten the list inside list:

```
var Result = (from orderdata in detailReport.SelectMany(x=>>x.OrderList)
             group orderdata by orderdata.OrderDate.Date into g
             select new
                   {
                     OrderDate = g.Key,
                     Count = g.Count()
                   }).ToList();
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE FIDDLE with SelectMany()](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9n8si6)

Comment: But see the detailReport is already of a Collection type so there is no such thing as detailReport.OrderList. IList<DetailReport> detailReport

Comment: use `SelectMany()` to flatten list inisde list